# Calculating euclidean distance from a dataframe with several column features

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, euclidean-distance

I have a dataframe like below and I need to calculate the euclidean distance.

```
a,b,c,d,e
10,11,13,14,9
11,12,14,15,10
12,13,15,16,11
13,14,16,17,12
14,15,17,18,13
15,16,18,19,14
16,17,19,20,15
17,18,20,21,16
18,19,21,22,17
19,20,22,23,18
20,21,23,24,19
21,22,24,25,20
22,23,25,26,21
23,24,26,27,22
24,25,27,28,23
```

I guess with only 2 column features say **a** and **b**, I can easily do:

```
def euclidean_distance(a, b):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((a - b)**2))
```

How can I calculate the euclidean distance of a dataframe with several column features like **a**, **b**, **c**, **d**, **e** above?

Comment: What do you mean with "several columns", a euclidean distance is between two points. You mean each column to every other column?

Comment: You can simply apply scikits euclidean_distances to your dataframe as it handles arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data has (15 dimensions, 5 points), and you want the Euclidean distance between each and every one of those points, if I am not mistaken.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# copied and pasted your data to a text file
df = pd.read_table("euclidean.txt", sep=',') 

> df.shape 
(15, 5)
```

`(15,5)` Distance matrix will be `5x5`. Initialize this matrix, calculate the Euclidean distance between each of these 5 points using `for` loops, and fill them into the distance matrix.

```
n = df.shape[1] # this number is 5 for the dataset you provided
dm = np.zeros((n,n)) # initialize the distance matrix to zero

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        dm[i,j] = np.sqrt(np.sum((df.iloc[:,i] - df.iloc[:,j])**2))
```

`dm` output is then:

```
> dm
array([[ 0.        ,  3.87298335, 11.61895004, 15.49193338,  3.87298335],
       [ 3.87298335,  0.        ,  7.74596669, 11.61895004,  7.74596669],
       [11.61895004,  7.74596669,  0.        ,  3.87298335, 15.49193338],
       [15.49193338, 11.61895004,  3.87298335,  0.        , 19.36491673],
       [ 3.87298335,  7.74596669, 15.49193338, 19.36491673,  0.        ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly the question, you want to create a distance matrix for all of your rows?

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}, {'a':4,'b':5,'c':6}])
distances = squareform(pdist(df.values, metric='euclidean'))
```

resulting in a matrix containing

```
array([[0.        , 5.19615242],
   [5.19615242, 0.        ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `cdist`:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
arr = df[['a','b','c','d']].values
dist_mat = cdist(arr,arr)
```

If you don't like external package, the distance matrix is:

```
dist_mat = ((arr[None,:,:] - arr[:,None,:])**2).sum(-1)**.5
```